# Ember.js and it's automagic properties / conventional behaviour

Tags: ember.js

I recently discovered ember.js and it caught my interest for it's sophistication and possibilities. I went through several learning materials so far:

- [Ember.js' own guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/)
- Several source codes (e.g. [sample ToDo app](https://github.com/emberjs/todos))
- [Presentations from Tom and Yehuda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ed_o3_59ME)

From these, I understood that there is a lot of "assumptions" about how the framework should be used, how should we name views, controllers and models and that **if we follow these conventions**, we can save a lot of code typing because **Ember.js can do that "out of box", by default.**

This is, of course, extremely handy, but only in the case when you really know WHAT is happening behind the scenes for you that you did not have to write. And from that come my questions:

**WHAT** is happening when we define one application template and one view, for example? What is done for us automatically? Is the applicationController instantiated for us? Or, do we have to create one manually? What about any other view / controller pairs that are not applicationViews/Controllers, like a subview (since applicationView and applicationController are somehow unique in that they MUST be present in any ember.js app ) ?

**WHAT** does the router ( API from 1.0pre4 ) do automatically for us if we only define a bunch of routes but do not override any of the router's default, conventional behaviour?

Personally, what would really help me understand the key concepts here is a **sample application** with a transition to another state **that would implement everything the application needs to do in order to work properly** ( meaning, it would not depend on any code that ember would do for us otherwise ). That way, I would be able to see the various parts at play and "re-engineer" the process in my head and, hopefully, understand the process in its completeness.

If this question is overly complex or vague please suggest how I could narrow down my interest.

Comment: The ember.js peepcode episode explains this very well and it will only set you back 12 bucks: https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs

Comment: I just was about to ask the same question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need much of anything to get started with EmberJS. I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nzXW9/ that highlights how simple a *simple* application can be. I've also created a superfluous `App.PetsCatsController` just to demonstrate how that automatically becomes the controller when you move into the `pets.cats` route.

You don't need an `applicationController` or `applicationView` to get started. From the `pets.index` route, Ember assumes the following by default: `PetsIndexController`, `PetsIndexView`, `PetsIndexRoute`.

From my understanding of EmberJS, let's take a simple example scenario (we don't have DS models at this stage) for when we move into the #/pets/cats route:

1. If available, consult the `PetsCatsRoute` for instructions about moving into this route;
2. Since Ember's controllers are singletons, check if we already have an instance of a `PetsCatsController`, if we do, go to #5, otherwise go to #3;
3. Check if there is a user defined `PetsCatsController`, if there is create an instance of it;
4. If there isn't a user defined `PetsCatsController`, instantiate an EmberJS generated `PetsCatsController` controller;
5. Find the corresponding `PetsCatsView`, if it exists, otherwise generate one automatically.

You'll notice as well from the JSFiddle, that you don't necessarily need to concern yourself with index routes, unless you need to as your project expands.

Comment: If you want to modify dom or class of your main app dom. you should define applicationView explicitly. otherwise you don't have to. Ember does it for you automatically, though you can't find App.ApplicationView in console.

Comment: if you have and a route definition and a template for the route. then the App will work fine. (if you followed the convention) controller and view for the route will be automatically created.

Comment: Hi @Wildhoney, even though you have taken a completely opposite approach than I originally asked for, your jsFiddle example certainly helped me a lot in understanding ember.js! At least I know not to care about some details like I did before.:) Thank you!